# Intuition behind interpolation and interpolating polynomials

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

What's the Intuition behind interpolation and why we mostly do polynomial interpolation?

I mean why do we prefer polynomials?

Is it because among functions polynomials are the ones whose behaviour we know well,and also they behave nicely like they are continuous,differentiable etc?

Comment: This is very vague.  We interpolate data for many reasonns, but oftenn because we wish to identify the underlying relations between variables (if there are any underlying relations).  We often use polynomials because they are easy to compute with.

Comment: @lulu This was the first time I came across Interpolation, because I have taken a course on numerical analysis,so it was something new for me,I didn't know it was too vague

Comment: Context is everything.  If you have reason to believe that your variables are connected by an exponential law, then interpolate using exponential functions. If you are trying to analyze musical tones, use periodic (trigonometric) functions. And so on. In context you ought to have some idea of what relation you are looking for.  Polynomials are a computationally straight forward way to get going.